# Unable to co-op in the forest after first boss

Tags: pc, dark-souls

On the PC, my friend and I entered the forest for the first time and used the White Soapstone to co-op (my friend hosted). We progressed and defeated the Butterfly, and thus I was returned back to my world.

We then tried to co-op again and it failed; neither of us ever saw each others soapstone markings. Sif is still alive, shouldn't either of us be able to co-op still? We were still in the same game session when we defeated the Butterfly (thus no network changes were made etc).

My friend is SL42 and I'm SL41. Our NAT is open, ports are forwarded, firewall is off. We are in the area where the Butterfly is, and I'm (have not defeated Butterfly) trying to summon him but still cannot see his soapstone.

Why can we not see each others soapstones to co-op again?

Comment: Which part of the forest are you in? Are you past the door into the part of the forest where the forest covenant is / Sif's fog wall is

Comment: @Shykin Still in the area with the Butterfly, who I have not defeated yet.

Comment: Which version are you on? PC? 360? PS3?

Comment: @Shykin First line in question indicates PC

Comment: Oops, In addition you can try inviting him to play with GFWL. It can cause the sign to appear.

Answer (score 1):

The only TRUE requirement for co-op is that you are within the 10% co-op level range of each other. In my experience co-op-ing with a friend on PC, it can be extremely finnicky to  get into each other's games due to many different servers, etc. I've found the best solution for making it work "better" are for you both to be in one of the co-op friendly Covenants (3 at the bottom):

http://darksouls.wikidot.com/covenants

It's quite easy to join Way of White even at the beginning of the game. Once the two of us both got into that covenant, we have had almost no trouble joining each other's games.